# Why exclude wwwroot from tsconfig?

Tags: asp.net, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-4.6

I'm working with a TypeScript project using an ASP.NET 5 template in VS.NET 2015. I added a `scripts/tsconfig.json` file and it contains the following `exclude` section by default:

```
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
```

However going through tutorials I've also seen that I should configure the TypeScript build output to the following directory:

```
"outDir": "../wwwroot"
```

Stating the definition of `exclude` from the official [TypeScript wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json):

> If the "exclude" property is specified, the compiler includes all
>   TypeScript (*.ts or *.tsx) files in the containing directory and
>   subdirectories except for those files or folders that are excluded.

My confusion is since the `tsconfig.json` file applies settings to the virtual typescript project within the folder where it is located, and mine is within the `/scripts` folder, do I still need that setting? Why would I exclude `wwwroot` and why was that setting added automatically? I don't plan on having a `wwwroot` folder within my `/scripts` folder, so I'm trying to understand why it should be excluded? Or is it added by default since I *could* of added my `tsconfig.json` folder to the root of my project and in that case one would want to exclude the `wwwroot` folder?

Answer (score 2):

The `wwwroot` dir is for the output files. In a typical ASP.NET 5 web project, your *.js/*.css files will be compiled from *.ts and *.less/*.sass. This source files are part of your project and the code you work on.

On build, change or publishing, you compile into i.e. *.js, merge them to one file for example and minify (aka uglify), then copy them to a folder in `wwwroot` as well as all static files of your web project.

With `exclude: "wwwroot"` you tell not to search there for *.less/*.sass/*.ts files as non of these files should ever be located there.

Comment: If any `.ts` files were in `wwwroot` wouldn't it make some kind of circular mess? The output is trying to build `.ts` files but they would be excluded from looking in that folder so it wouldn't do anything?

Comment: It's not just about js. the new .xproj files have no concept of included/exlcuded files like .csproj had. In .csproj you explicitly had to include the cs file to the project in order for it to be compiled (if add file via VS it happened automatically). in .xproj all files are included by default (drop in file in the explorers folder structure and its available in VS), so we have to exclude option to exclude certain folders from compiling (i.e. `node_modules`, `bower_components` as they contain packages, not our own code.

Comment: For `wwwroot` this is always the case, as it's the public folder that contains only compiled (css, js) or static non-code files (images)

Answer (score 1):

Type script compiler searches for typescript files (**input**) and compiles them in every folder. With the exclude you tell the compiler to do not search the `wwwroot` folder for (**input**) typescript files. the `outDir` tell the typescript compiler to **output** the compiled files to the `wwwroot`. Your compiled files can then be served to the client.